Gravitational waves from inflation
Primordial gravitational waves from inflation are a common fingerprint or proof of inflationary models.
What are the main imprints and features of waveforms from inflation if we could track and measure them? Note I am not asking about the B-mode smoking gun test, but about PGW waveforms. For instante,...Are they continuous or transient? What are their frequencies? Are there many types of inflationary gravitational waves?
Bonus: how far (in years) are we of detecting primordial gravitational waves?

Might be useful to you/anyone answering: Primordial Gravitational Waves 2024; "Using currently available cosmic microwave background data from Planck, ACT and SPT separately or their combinations with BK18 B-mode polarization and DESI observations, we give the strongest constraints on primordial gravitational waves so far."
